# For Loops in C to print out individual ints.

Tags: c, for-loop

I want to print out each integer of an int individually using a for loop. I am doing this because I want to print things in between some of the single ints. So if the number was 4564, I want to print out 4 5 6 4. Is there a quick way to do this?

I know how to do it in java but I am new to C and am not sure.

Comment: The answer is C will be largely the same as in Java. What is it about C that you're not sure about?

Comment: Basically how do I find the length of the int.

Comment: How would you find the length of the int in Java?

Comment: Like using the for loop would I do?  for(int i = 0; i < theInt.length(); i++) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this shall help

```
while(num!=0) {
   printf("%d", num%10); //your last digit, you can store it in an array of characters as well
   num = num/10 ;
}
```

*Note* : you've got to reverse the order while using the digits

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for

Comment: Please mark this answer as the answer then